# Xamarin xaml bind list

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin

I'm currently going through the XamarinAlliance challenge but I stumbled on number 3. I managed to get the backend app up and running and connected sql express to the database and inserted some data. All ok so far.

But now I can't seem to get the data to a list on the app. It always says the count is 0 and shows nothing. Not true. I connected to the database through VS to the server and made a query and the data is there.

So, this is my mainpage:

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public static string mobileServiceClientUrl = "http://onepiecealliance.azurewebsites.net/";
    public static MobileServiceClient Client = new MobileServiceClient(mobileServiceClientUrl);
    public static IMobileServiceTable<Character> CharacterTable = Client.GetTable<Character>();
    private static List<Character> characterList { get; set; }

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        characterList = new List<Character>();
        GetCharactersAsync();
        BindingContext = new CharacterModelList();
    }

    async public void list_ItemTapped(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e)
    {
        Character item = (Character)e.Item;
        await Navigation.PushAsync(new Characters(item.Name, item.Description));
        ((ListView)sender).SelectedItem = null;

    }

    public async void GetCharactersAsync()
    {
        characterList = await CharacterTable.ToListAsync();
    }

    //Model
    public class Character
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }


    //Controller
    public class CharacterModelList : BindableObject
    {
        public List<Character> CharacterList1
        {
            get { return characterList; }
            set { characterList = value; }
        }

        public CharacterModelList()
        {

        }

    }

}
```

And this is another class:

```
public partial class Characters : ContentPage
{
    public Characters(string name, string description)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Title = name;
        lbl_Description.Text = description;
    }

    private async void btn_Back_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        await Navigation.PopAsync();
    }
}
```

And the app (nothing special about this one):

```
public partial class App : Application
    {
        public App()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage());
        }

        protected override void OnStart()
        {
            // Handle when your app starts
        }

        protected override void OnSleep()
        {
            // Handle when your app sleeps
        }

        protected override void OnResume()
        {
            // Handle when your app resumes
        }
    }
```

Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong? If needed I can also post the xaml. It's probably nothing special, but as a beginner in Xamarin I'm going crazy about this! Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: The error I'm getting:

> {System.MissingMethodException: Method
>   'System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.set_AutomaticDecompression' not
>   found.   at
>   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceHttpClient.CreatePipeline
>   (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] handlers) [0x0000a] in
>   <42e24ce875d34485ad11c4f8aebb904a>:0    at
>   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceHttpClient..ctor
>   (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] handlers, System.Uri
>   applicationUri, System.String installationId) [0x00014] in
>   <42e24ce875d34485ad11c4f8aebb904a>:0    at
>   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceClient..ctor
>   (System.Uri mobileAppUri, System.Net.Http.HttpMessageHandler[]
>   handlers) [0x00085] in <42e24ce875d34485ad11c4f8aebb904a>:0    at
>   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceClient..ctor
>   (System.String mobileAppUri, System.Net.Http.HttpMessageHandler[]
>   handlers) [0x00008] in <42e24ce875d34485ad11c4f8aebb904a>:0    at
>   One_Piece.MainPage..ctor () [0x0001b] in
>   C:\Users\Fabio\Desktop\Challenge\One
>   Piece\One_Piece\MainPage.xaml.cs:24 }

Comment: Your GetCharactersAsync is returning void. It should be: public async Task GetCharactersAsync. And you should call it from the overridden OnNavigated method and invoke it with an await expression:await GetCharactersAsync();

Comment: Forgot to say that I had it public async Task, before. But I got the same. Perhaps it will be diferent if I call from that override. I'll try it in the morning and I'll give you some feedback. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Also, if you are using data binding for the list, bind it with mode OneWay and use an ObservableCollection or James Montemagno's ObservableRangeCollection to store the data. You will have to get the data from CharacterTable and foreach over it like: `(await CharacterTable.ToListAsync()).ForEach(p=> characterList.Add(p));`

Comment: I think this is binding issue 'BindingContext = new CharacterModelList();' What itemsource you binding in xaml?

Comment: @sauravsahu, I was trying on OnNavigated override but it looks like there is no method with that name. Could you give me an exemple? Also, I've seen that ObservableCollection, but what is the diference between that and a list?

Comment: @JesseJiang, I'm binding to labels. But that's working just fine without the backend app. So, I don't think that's the problem. But then agian, I could be wrong.

Comment: You can read about ObservableCollection here: https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection%3CT%3E/

Comment: An ObservableCollection makes sure your bindings are notified about items added, or removed and update your UI. List don't have this implementation.

Comment: "System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'One_Piece.MainPage' threw an exception."

I tried to debug it but it doesn't even go to the MainPage. It gets stuck od the App... :\

Comment: I fixed that. It was the static properties. Probably being instantiated before the rest of the solution.

But I keep getting and error on "Client = new MobileServiceClient(mobileServiceClientUrl);"
I posted the error on the main post.

Why is it so hard to connect to a backend app? I don't understand...

Comment: Ok, I've been searching and it seems I had to install a nugget package to handle http on the backend app (Microsoft.Net.Http). When debbuging it now goes through the MobileServiceClient line successfully. But it's still throwing an error and I don't know where. The popup just says "An unhandled exception occured.". And apparently the list count is still 0...

Comment: I ended up using their code (maybe when I have more time I'll take a look at this and try to see what went wrong...) and the up was up and running but I was getting no information. Then I realised that the Id on the Character class had to be a string, rather than an int, because on the backend it will send a string. Basic mistake, but still... Problem solved, for now. On to challenge 4!